# Is there a classic Emacs theme for Vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Emacs theme.el package has a theme called "Classic" that looks like this
[image]

Looking for VSCode theme that looks *exactly* the same.

Comment: Is `emacs` tag really appropriate here? I'm **guessing** most of the emacs users answering questions on SO/SE wouldn't really know much about vscode themes. Hence, I'm not surprised someone had downvoted your question (well, I balanced that situation by adding my vote - probably because I dislike downvotes without explanations.)

Comment: Thanks, removed emacs tag,